# Additional Query String Causing Page Not To Load

Tags: php, url, query-string

I have a link that I'm creating where I'd like to have a few query strings to pass data. I tried 1 query string in the URL and it works fine:

`http://www.example.com/video/?video=VideoOne`

However, whenever I add an additional query string parameter to the URL, I get sent to a 404 page:

```
http://www.example.com/video/?video=VideoOne&name=Something
```

Am I missing something completely obvious? What could be causing this? I've used query strings elsewhere on the site and had no issues.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules acting on this?

Comment: I don't believe so. Like I said, I've used query strings elsewhere on the same site with success.

Comment: Is `name` the only variable that causes the page to break, or does adding any second variable to the query string break it? What if you specify `name` but not `video`? (It doesn't matter if you page requires you to specify `video` to work properly; this is just to test what's causing the 404 error.)

Comment: Weird, I thought I tried others as well, but name appears to be the only one that is causing the 404. Thanks for the debugging hint, I just needed someone else to help me think this through.

Comment: huh, I had the same problem with 'year' name.